# ¿Como invocar un fragment desde otra actividad?

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Tengo en el MainActivity 2 fragments, cuando paso a la SecondActivity desde allí quiero volver al fragment2 del MainActivity pasandole unos datos.

Pero me da un error de desbordamiento el tratar de obtener el fragment desde MainActivity:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .getFragments()
                    .get(1)
```

El fragment Manager no tiene ningún fragment.

Alguna sugerencia?
Gracias.

Comment: que datos quieres pasar (de Activity2 a Fragment2 de Activity1)?

Comment: 2 Strings y un int

Answer (score 0):

Al volver de un Activity a otro es reiniciar la actividad por lo que el fragmentManager no tiene ningún fragment.

Para ello, desde la segunda actividad, hay que pasarle al intent algún identificador (un nombre o un número) para luego desde el `onCreate` de la actividad invocar el fragment que se desea mostrar:

```
Intent intentMain = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intentMain.putExtras("previousFragment", 2); 
startActivity(intentMain);
```

Y desde el `onCreate` de MainActivity:

```
int previousFragment = getIntent().getExtras("previousFragment");
if(previousFragment == 2) {
    // llamar al fragment
    SegundoFragment fragment = SegundoFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentManager ft = getSupportFragmentManager();
    ft.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, 
    fragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: No tengo un Fragment en el activity, tengo un viewPager pero no logro hacer que fragmentManager cambie al segundoFragment, cambie el fragment_container por el viewPager (ft.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewPager,fragment).commit();) pero funciona, no sirve con viewPager?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide 
Es muy diferente, pero igual usa un Fragment. En este caso, en el constructor del fragment, habría que pasarle el número de la página para que el adaptador la devuelva.

Comment: El problema es que cuando obtengo el item (Fragment) no se por qué todo es nulo, si me devuelve la instancia del Fragment que es pero, no puedo manipular ninguna View, es por lo que ud menciona anteriormente, pero no logro conseguir que se muestre en el viewPager.En es eejemplo todo lo hacen desde el mismo Activity

Answer (score 0):

no he podido hacerlo de la manera como lo estaba pensando,
tuve que agregar un listener en el fragment, en MainActivity implementar ese listener
y utilizar :

```
 viewPager.setCurrentItem(1); //On MainActivity
```

y sobrescribir el onAttach()del Fragment2 para capturar el listener
y en el   onViewCreated() invocar el listener pasando (this) como parámetro, desde MainActivity capturo el evento, obtengo los datos del bundary e invoco el
método del Fragment2 pasandole los datos.

No se si sea la mejor solución.

Comment: y con esto pudiste enviar datos de la  Activity2 a la Activity1(Fragment 2)?

Comment: Si, utilizando la MainActivity como canal.

Comment: Debería marcar esta respuesta como la correcta.